# unix utility to write HTTP PUT requests to file

Tags: bash, centos, logs, webserver

I have a networking appliance that **only** supports remote syslog via dumping to a http/https URI. It supports optional basic authentication, can switch between native/JSON formats and... that's it.

[image]

[update] I found using `nc` that it just sends a `PUT /uri/ HTTP/1.1` where `uri` is whatever I enter into the URI field above, and expects an `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response

I'm just looking for a tool that can write the data from these requests to a file, and handle responding to the sender device. It looks like `nc` can handle this with some scripting and jank, but I'm not sure it's a good tool for the job.

Comment: Not sure about "extremely basic", but [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html) can read from HTTP. I am sure it can also process JSON.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, but how about `nc -l 80 > dump.log`?

Comment: logstash is a bit outside of my nonexistant budget for this. `nc` will probably do what I need, but I'll have to get it to handle some basic http responses. I will try it out.

Comment: Rsyslog has an HTTP input module which looks appropriate for your needs: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/imhttp.html

Comment: Webdav, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dumb little webservice with `nc`, and that seems to be working for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
  # reply to web traffic with a basic 200 response
  do cat /usr/local/bin/200.http |
    # listen on port 80
    nc -l 80 |
    # save any json to a file
    grep '{"transaction"' >> /path/to/logs.json
done
```

I wrapped it into a service and firewalled it to that specific device.